# Using .htaccess with apache + php-fpm + event mpm

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, fpm

The official Apache documentation [says](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM) vaguely about this:

> Warning: when you ProxyPass a request to another server (in this case,
>   the php-fpm daemon), authentication restrictions, and other
>   configurations placed in a Directory block or .htaccess file, **may be
>   bypassed**.

So, can I still somehow use .htaccess in this setup?

Comment: that is because of the question of who authenticates whom. consider the route: internet -> proxy host -> real server. now, does proxy authenticate client on internet or your real server your proxy host ? There are several considerations, like passing headers through proxy to real server, authentication scheme etc. Thats the reason for the warning.

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu AFAIK, the problem happens because Apache passes all .php requests to fast-cgi server and it does not know how to handle .htaccess. Not sure what authentication has to do with this.

Comment: as I said, its a matter of who does the authentication, ie, processing, ie, handling the .htaccess file (as .htaccess usually contains rules for who can access what, how to access it etc, as well as configuration directives). apache as the proxy, or php-fpm as the real host (in your scenario). And as you said, php-fpm has nothing to do with htaccess, so...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190279/can-i-override-php-setting-in-htaccess-when-using-php-fpm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I Override PHP Setting in htaccess When Using PHP-FPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190279/can-i-override-php-setting-in-htaccess-when-using-php-fpm)