# PHP-FPM + Apache 2.4 mod rewrite issues when .php file is in url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I`m having trouble with my mod rewrite rules. They are working fine, except when a .php filename is passed in the url. My rules are ignored in this case and I get a file not found error.

Apache 2.4 conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin postmaster@xxx.xxx
  DocumentRoot /srv/www/development.x.nl/x/html
  ServerName development.x.nl
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/development.x.nl-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/development.x.nl-access.log combined
  Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/srv/www/development.x.nl/x/html/
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory />
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /srv/www/development.x.nl/x/html>
    AllowOverride Authconfig Limit FileInfo Options Indexes
    Options Includes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file (which resides in /srv/www/development.x.nl/html/public

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/(.*)$                                             /public/index.php                                                       [B,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^browse/([0-9]*)/(.*)$                              /public/content.php?ts=$1&url=$2                        [B,NE,L]
RewriteRule ^latest/(.*)$                                               /public/today.php?url=$1                                        [B,NE,L]
```

Example link that works fine: http://development.x.nl/public/browse/20180103165107/http://www.aaa.nl/aanvragen-of-regelen/reizen-en-id_46991/

Link with .php in them do not work:
http://development.x.nl/public/latest/https:/www.x.nl/document.php?m=52&fileid=83059&f=b7728857dcb2584c67189f28c24755f4&attachment=0

This used to work fine on mod_php

What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I Override PHP Setting in htaccess When Using PHP-FPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190279/can-i-override-php-setting-in-htaccess-when-using-php-fpm)

Comment: Php fpm doesn't do .htaccess.  see dup for options.

Comment: It parses the rewriterules except when the argument contains *.php in the url. If I rename the .htaccess file, this link doenst work anymore: http://development.x.nl/public/browse/20180103165107/http://www.aaa.nl/aanvragen-of-regelen/reizen-en-id_46991/