# htaccess stops working when I add max upload

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am trying to upload a wordpress theme but it always fail because it needs more upload and post size.

This is the .htaccess file I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

php_value memory_limit 256
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 1000


# END WordPress
```

When it is like that , the site keeps refreshing without showing any content
but when I remove the other lines and write is as such:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

the website is displayed.

I have been googling for hours but didn't find anything that might help.
Anyone with previous experience knows what is happening or how to solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just tested and I see the same behaviour, can see an error 500 in the logs

```
GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 185
```

When I set `php_value memory_limit 256M`, the error is resolved.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

> memory_limit integer
>
> This sets the maximum amount of memory **in bytes** that a script is
>   allowed to allocate. This helps prevent poorly written scripts for
>   eating up all available memory on a server. Note that to have no
>   memory limit, set this directive to -1.

For `php_value` to work inside `.htaccess` you need:

- `mod_php`. Doesn't work with `php-fpm`, but there's [another mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38190279/can-i-override-php-setting-in-htaccess-when-using-php-fpm#answer-38191380).
- `AllowOverride` set to `Options` or `All`

I'd try to remove one directive at a time and [enabling errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) (which ironically can be done in `.htaccess`)

Comment: it's a rather old looking panel, I am trying to search for what you asking about

Comment: I deleted multiple old htaccess I found on the website. now it is giving me :

Comment: link you follow expired

Comment: In the Wordpress support forum [thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/the-link-you-followed-has-expired) they suggest the exact same solution you are trying. Maybe look for `php.ini` in your config panel and try setting it there.

Answer (score 0):

Change php_value memory_limit 256 to php_value memory_limit 256M and it should work. So you should have:

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 1000
```

Comment: What type of server is it nginx or apache?

Comment: The server is Apache

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache or private browsing I am using those very entry on another site and it loads fine

https://screenshots.firefox.com/2LfPo9NbckEFr3Mg/desires.com.jm

Comment: i have been able to get the error log , can you please get a look at it?

Comment: I will take a look at it in the meantime try adding each line one by one to see which is really causing the error